# When I press the link does not go top the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

javascript :

```
   function yourFunction(intValue){

     $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'pagination.php',
  data: 'page='+ intValue,
  success: function(raspuns){
    $('#resulte').html(raspuns);


  }
});
}
```

html:

```
<a href="#"  onclick="yourFunction('.($this->page + 1).$queryUrl.')">next</a>
```

When I press the link goes top the page.
What to do to remain in place?

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0);"

Comment: You can also try `onclick="yourFunction('.($this->page + 1).$queryUrl.');return false;"`

Comment: Shay Elkayam work like you said, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `return false` at the end of function or use the `preventDefault()` method to prevent the default action.